# Alternative Table Row Colors

Tags: php, html

Checked already  answered questions but unsuccessful.

I have table populated from database.

How to make alternative color for  each group ? such as this

[image]

This is the code

```
<?php
while ( $rq  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_N, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>

<div class="center2">
  <div class="datagrid">
    <table>
        <tr><td> <?php echo $rq[category_id]; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you

P.S.

It's a no problem to create  row alternative such as this

[image]

But I looking for  GROUP by ID

Comment: Hey Green_Crocodile! Here on StackOverflow, we help fix problems and offer suggestions based on code *you've already produced*. Could you show us your current HTML (after output, I'm not sure the PHP is necessary here), CSS, and JavaScript you're using to try to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include server side language and basic code structure, html. Thanks

Comment: Your tags are Javascript and HTML. Does this mean no CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css nth child.

For even/odd

```
Tr:nth-child(even){
 Background-color: #446;
}
```

For Class

```
Tr.bg{
 Background-color: #446;
}
```

For more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

With PHP alternating based on variable. This code will change class if the first letter changes.

```
<?php

 $first_letter  '';
 //Change class to true to invert background color
 $class = false;


//Warning isn't Category id supposed to be a string is so add quotes

 while ( $rq = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_N, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
//Using shorthand echo <?=
//

     // CSS Class Name
    $val = (string) trim( strtolower( $rq[category_id] ) ); //Make sure its of string type

    //This will set the class to either true or false
    //If class is true, the column will have a classname of bg
    if( !empty( trim($rq[category_id]) ) && strlen( $val ) > 0 && $first_letter !== $val[0];   ){
        $class = !$class; //Invert class
        $first_letter = $val[0];
    }

   ?> <div class="center2"> 
    <div class="datagrid"> 
       <table> 
          <tr class='<?= $class ? 'bg' : null  ?>' ><td> <?php echo $rq[category_id]; ?></td></tr> 
       </table> 
    </div> 
   </div><?php

}
```

Comment: This could work if the alternative color is on every other row. But for this question, it seems that it's for each row *with a different starting character*, which is a variable number of rows.

Comment: Then add more detail to the question!  If it's server side you can add a class to the table row. If it's static data you will need to add class after the page loads.

Comment: I definitely don't disagree with you here - I've already asked for clarification on this question above! I'm just guessing based on the image, honestly.

Comment: this is a code  <?php
while ( $rq  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result_N, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>

<div class="center2">
  <div class="datagrid">
    <table>
        <tr><td> <?php echo $rq[category_id]; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Dear Edwin - you are genius.  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you're iterating through the rows with an index, check the value of `index % 2` which say's "what's the remainder, if any, of `index` divided by `2`?"

If it equals `0` then set it's class to something like `even-row` otherwise set it's class to something like `odd-row`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` to get all elements and loop through the returned array, setting the background color on every second element. See below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
    <p class="row">A Row</p>
  </body>
  <script>
    const rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
    for (i=0;i<rows.length;i+=2)
      rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  </script>
</html>
```

If you want to use CSS, use nth-child.

Comment: No I need different.  I need color by group.

Comment: @Green_Crocodile If you can change your code into just HTML I can help you.